# html tags in the same line do not work

Tags: html, css

In my html i have two input tags and i want them on the same line, after i search and try more code.

It doesn't change anything, what wrong is my code?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Meaning:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="">
            <div class="lnw">
                <span class="inline">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="meaning[]" id="meaning " style="float: right">
                <input type="image" src="/images/pjdict/plus.png" alt="Submit" width="48" height="48" class="add_field_button">
                </span>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are using form-control class then it will be one in row. Remove that class if you need 2 input in one line.

Comment: @Leothelion Didn't mention it's Bootstrap.

Comment: @JensonMJohn did not get your point?

Comment: it have other way?? ,because it change style my from

Comment: @Danusorn so you want input box and image to next of it, right?

Comment: other way to don't remove form-contro

Comment: @Leothelion OP didn't mention it's Bootstrap infact. Or Am I Wrong??

Comment: @JensonMJohn op wants both input in one row but as he is using form-control means first input box will take 100% then no space for second input box. Simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have give some width for input["type="text"] or input["type="image"] like below:

Otherwise you cad custom class in form-control class and replease this class to .form-control

See [Bootply link](http://www.bootply.com/KFA7LbDxkx)

```
.form-control {
  float: left !important;
  width: 90%;
}
.add_field_button {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10%;
}
```

Comment: @Danusorn you can add custom class in form-control and given css for form-control replease with your custom class.

Comment: I am given the css on input class. you can replace this class with button.

Comment: some problem is if i click add text is not in same line

Comment: can you please create fiddle link then i will check and let you know

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a `float:right` in your code a form could simple be put

`<input type="text">
 <input type="text">`

and they will show up beside each other also you should always put the type first

Comment: and what about form-control class?

Comment: i need type text and type image

Comment: then change the type accordingly im not gonna right code for you just putting in some education(sorry if this sounds rude its been a long day)

Answer (score 0):

simply you can use display:inline-block to container of input tags

```
<html>
  <body><div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Meaning:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="">
            <div class="lnw">
                <span class="inline" style="display:inline-block"> //inline-block added here
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="meaning[]" id="meaning " style="float: right">
                <input type="image" src="/images/pjdict/plus.png" alt="Submit" width="48" height="48" class="add_field_button">
                </span>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This won't work because spans are inline elements by default (and nothing questioned here requires block elements), and if anything, you'd need to set the input elements themselves to render as inline elements, not their container - however, input elements render as inline by default.

Comment: i try delete span but same result

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code for the same.

```css
.inline  input[type="text"] {
float:left;
margin:10px 10px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Meaning:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="">
            <div class="lnw">
                <span class="inline">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="meaning[]" id="meaning " >
                <input type="image" src="/images/pjdict/plus.png" alt="Submit" width="48" height="48" class="add_field_button">
                </span>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make a new css style sheet to make it custom  and add under the bootstarp css then it will work. I think you are using the above of bootstarp. Also take the parent class for support like .form-group .inline  input

Comment: no i external your css and under bootstrap css it not wor

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the type of your input field to 'image', which according to [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_inputs.asp) isn't valid in bootstrap, and in general isn't valid for html. I can only guess what you're trying to do, but from the way things look, you want:

- a text input field
- a submit button to the right of the text input field
- an image instead of the regular submit button appearance

If that is accurate, take a look at the following snippet:

```css
#formElementContainer {
  margin-top: 60px; /* this is only important for display within this snippet */
}

#formElementContainer input[type='text'] {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
}

#formElementContainer input[type='submit'] {
  background: transparent url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/eb603bf5dd01c06880fdb8e4e1d04df3?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1') center center no-repeat;
  border: none;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div id="formElementContainer">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" value="" />
</div>
```